# Easily transportable encryption between computers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, encryption, rsa

I've (finally) successfully got 
*System.Configuration.Configuration.ConfigurationSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection*
working to en/de-crypt an XML config file.
But I [just read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561476/encrypt-winforms-app-config-connection-string-without-machine-specific-encryptio#comment32565047_21561476) that both `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` and `DataProtectionConfigurationProvider` will only work on *one* given computer, which makes sense now that I think about it.

What is the easiest way to enable users to share an encrypted XML config file and allow them to all open it. I [read about rolling my own encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string) but is there **any** easier way?

Comment: You can use symmetric key encryption, such as Rijndael, etc. and just use a shared key (password).

Comment: You need to use the same MachineKey.

Comment: What are you trying to protect here? A service endpoint? A local database? Something else?

Comment: @GregoryABeamer, an XML config file containing usernames/passwords. Users need to be able to load it, modify it, save it - then share it with another user.

Comment: I wouldn't store those kind of information localy, winforms can be easily reversed, so your encyption/decryption methods can be found, I suggest you to save that in a database using a webservice.